# Getting image width and height from compass sprites

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, css-sprites

I'm having trouble getting the image width and height when generating a sprite from compass. I'm using Scout for my live watch and already configured my images folder. I have my images that I want to sprite in a folder called common.

Here's my code

```
@import "common/*.png";
.facebook { @include common-sprite(facebook); }
```

This works and generates the background position, but I want to get the width and height.

Any would be awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. Adding `$common-sprite-dimensions: true;` ([link to compass sprite options docs](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/customization-options/)) will put the width and height into the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want ALL your sprites usages to be defined with the image size, you can also:

```
@import "common/*.png";
.facebook { @include common-sprite(facebook, true); }
```

That `true`parameter will generate width and height for the image only in the `.facebook` class definition.